# multi-column listbox xaml windows app project

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, listbox, windows-store-apps

I want an listbox with multiple columns and rows. Exactly what's described [here](http://kristofmattei.be/2010/03/16/multi-column-listview/).

The problem with this solution is that the 'UniformGrid' isn't supported in an windows 8 app project. So, how can I achieve the same in an windows 8 app project?

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Comment: Nope, haven't found the answer yet

Comment: Does a GridView meet your requirements?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903669/choosing-between-xamls-listview-and-gridview-in-winrt